# Converted TIF->Jpeg-image get wrong colors on server but not locally

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, image-processing, imageresizer

I have a thumbnail handler that produce jpeg thumbs from larger tif and jpeg images. It works great locally but on server the colors turn ugly on some of the tif images. Red turns to purple etc.

I have two versions of the handler, one that uses GDI+ for resizing and one that uses imageresizer (http://imageresizing.net/) for that. These results in the same problem.

Server and developer machine uses .net 4.0

Server is Windows server 2008 and I run Windows 7

Someone had the same problem?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect the problem is related to ICC profiles. Adding `ignoreicc=true` to the ImageResizer command string may ameliorate the problem.

It's likely your server either has a wacky ICC profiled tied to the display, or doesn't have the ICC profile installed that is referenced in the image.

If you want to avoid ICC issues, it's probably easiest to use the [WIC](http://imageresizing.net/plugins/wic) or [FreeImage](http://imageresizing.net/plugins/freeimage) pipelines for the [ImageResizer](http://imageresizing.net), as they're less likely to be affected by color calibration wackiness on the server. Unlike the default pipeline, they require Full Trust - this won't work on a shared hosting plan.